# Getting end result of URL

Tags: php, html, regex, url

So I've seen other posts that show how to do this, but only with "clean" URLs like `example.com/this/this`, what I want to do I get the username from this URL `example.com/profile.php?username=joe` So that I'd end up getting say Joe as a result. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `$_GET['username']` to get the result.

Comment: RTM http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo your $_GET value like so:

> echo $_GET['username'];

It will return:

> joe

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username']!="")
{
  echo $_GET['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see a url string line the following

`profile.php?user=foo&name=bar`

You can access the parameters after the `?`. They will be stored in the `$_GET` `array`. The ampersand is the separator of variable name and value pairs. In this case: `user=foo`, the variable name is on the left side, of the seperator '=', `user` accessed by `$_GET['user']` and the value of an `echo` would be `foo`.